# I can't show one by one the items of an array of a javascript in html

Tags: javascript, html

i can't get this to work correctly, the idea is make a marquee that shows one letter past 0,5 seconds, in the HTML file i have a

```js
const frase = "Mi primer programa en JS";
const marquee = frase.split('');
const divMaquee = document.getElementById('marquee');
console.log(marquee);

for (let y = 0; y < marquee.length; y++) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    let p = document.createElement('p');
    p.innerText = marquee[y];
    divMaquee.appendChild(p);
    console.log(marquee[y]);
  }, 500);
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the same `500ms` for all `element` to appear after the same interval time.

Just change from

```
  setTimeout(function() {
    ...
  }, 500);
```

to

```
  setTimeout(function() {
    ...
  }, y * 500);
```

```js
const frase = "Mi primer programa en JS";
const marquee = frase.split('');
const divMaquee = document.getElementById('marquee');


for (let y = 0; y < marquee.length; y++) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    let p = document.createElement('p');
    p.innerText = marquee[y];
    divMaquee.appendChild(p);
  }, y * 500);
};
```

```html
<div id="marquee"></div>
```